# How do I allocate between passive and active strategy using active risk budget?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, risk-management

Lets say I have 100 million dollars. My active risk budget is 5%. I have an active fund that has active risk of 10%. What will be my mix in dollar terms of this active port and passive etf (assume passive ETF has 0 active risk)?

I have 2 answers, 1 says its "Allocation to active fund = Active risk budget / Active risk of active fund" ie in this case will be 5/10 = 50% into active fund.

The other answer is Active Fund Allocation = minimum(Active Fund Active Risk, Active Risk Budget) ie only 5% to Active fund (5 million dollars)

Which one is right? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please remind me what the definition of *active risk* of a fund is.

Comment: Hi nbbo2, active risk is tracking error of a fund against its benchmark.

Comment: Then I think in your example you can allocate half of your money to the active fund and have to allocate the other half to an index fund that follows the benchmark.

Comment: The 1st criterion looks at tracking error = std dev of $r_r-b_i$ like you said. The 2d criterion seems to be based on a different definition of active risk, where the "worst possible deviation" of the portfolio from the benchmark must never exceed 10%. In this case you can invest 5% in this Active fund and keep investing in other similar active funds until you exhaust your budget (expressed in dollars?), then you invest the rest in the index fund. So it is a more conservative approach. (But I am not sure my interpretation is correct).